# Splitting Title from full name in R using strsplit

Tags: r

I am working with some Titanic data and am trying to pull JUST the title out of the full name.

Some entries have 2-word last names, so I have been trying to use strsplit to get only the title after a comma. Here is an example of some of the data entries:

-Davidson, Mr Thornton

-Davidson, Mrs Thornton (Orian Hays)

-de Villiers, Madame Berthe

this is what I have tried and I am getting a "non-character argument"

```
titanic <- strsplit(titanic$name, ", ")
```

When I try as.character I get an error: argument "split" is missing, with no default.

```
titanic <- strsplit(as.character(titanic$Name, ", "))
```

This is my first time using strsplit so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here, `as.character` should have a closing bracket after the `$Name`

```
strsplit(as.character(titanic$Name), ", ")
```

Comment: If it's just a typo, why not mark it as such?

Comment: Can you please vote to close those in the future? With some effort, we can all help to keep this site free from questions that are not useful for future readers. Thank you!